# Online/Offline status computation rules

Tags: getstream-io

Good Day,
is it possible to share the rules of considering a user online or offline; and how this affect the computation of concurrent users.

I used the flutter package, I have quit the application and uninstall it and the user still has the status online ?

Am I supposed to add a code in the dispose function ? Or it is based on the Idle time?

Is it possible to share Stream's policy regarding this ?

Thanks

Comment: More info here: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/presence_format/?language=dart

"The last_active field is updated when a user connects and then refreshed every 15 minutes."

In Flutter, unless you override `onBackgroundEventReceived` then the user should be disconnected as soon as the app goes to the background.

How are you listening/updating the user connection status? Is it possible that you have this user connected somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the info and for your time.
I am using stream_chat_flutter widgets. And no, the user isn't connected somewhere else but I didn't wait for 15 minutes.